# How to have option already be selected when the Select2 4.0.1 widget opens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I currently have a functioning widget that takes in multiples options. The widget is inside of a popup window with a "Save" button along with other buttons. When I click "Save", the popup window closes, saves the selections onto a database, automatically runs the query that's in the database, and displays the results in a DataView.

Now when I open the popup window again, the text field in the Select2 widget is empty. I would like for it to fetch the data that's in the database and display them in the widget when it opens. I have it set up so that it returns an array of Strings that is supposed to be the ID (that's all I need for the widget to retrieve the proper data).

So my question is: **how do I go about modifying the widget so that it can take in an array and display them as already selected options when the widget is created?**

I'm actually not too sure what showing my code will do in this case but just in case, here they are:

```
$("#select2").select2({
  placeholder: "Select materials...",
  closeOnSelect: false,
  ajax: {
    url: this.targetUrl,
    delay: 200,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        code: params.term ? params.term + "*" : "*",
        page: params.page || 1
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < (data.length >= 25 ? 25 : data.length); i++) {
        results.push({
          id: data[i].code,
          text: data[i].code
        });
      }
      return {
        itemCode: results,
        results: results,
        pagination: false
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  maximumSelectionLength: 5,
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }
});
```

Comment: Any chance you fixed this?? If not I will try to help you out

Comment: @Reddy No I haven't been able to get it to work...your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `I would like for it to fetch the data that's in the database and display them in the widget when it opens` you want to do this from the second time the pop up is opened?? what if there was nothing done when the first time pop up was opened? And what data do you want to show in the pop up the second time that's different from the first time?

Comment: @Reddy I'd like for the popup to contain the options that's I've selected. So as long as it's not updated, not just the second time opening it but rather any time after that as well. And if nothing's added/changed, I have it so that the "Save" button is disabled, so I guess nothing different the second time around.

Comment: So you say that you just want to preserve the sate of the popup right??

Comment: Yup. And because it's already being stored as an array, my thought was that maybe I can somehow modify the widget to take in the array to have those options be selected.

Comment: are you creating the popup again and again for each show?? or are you just doing modal hide and show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105575/discussion-between-sparky-and-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

Select2 will trigger a few different events when different actions are taken using the component, allowing you to add custom hooks and perform actions.
such as: "change" event, Triggered whenever an option is selected or removed.

so you can use

```
$("#select2").val($selected).trigger("change");
```

after your code in your question to programatic control your select2.

above $selected is the data you request from your sever side. It should be an array, like ["12", "23", "34"].

Hope to help you.

Reference [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control)